# Oversampling a class in classification problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, oversampling

I have nearly `100000` data point with `15` features for 'disease' and 'no disease' as target.

But my data is imbalanced. `97%` of my data is no disease and `3%` is disease.
To overcome this I manually created disease data by creating `7` copies from the actual data and merged it with the original data.
using this code.

```
#selecting data with disease is 1 
# Even created unique 'patient ID' by adding a dummy letter as a suffix to the #original ID.
ia = df[df['disease']==1]
dup = pd.DataFrame()
for i,j in zip(['a','b','c','d','e','f'],['B','C','E','F','G','H']):
    i = ia.copy()    
    i['dum'] =  j
    i["patient ID"] = i["Employee Code"]+ i['dum']
    dup= pd.concat([dup,i])
# adding the copies to the original data
df = pd.concat([dup,df])
```

Please let me know if this is the correct method for oversampling.